# Can`t find imdbpy2sql.py script from cinemagoer (former IMDbPY) package

Tags: python, imdbpy

I've just installed cinemagoer (IMDbPY) from its repository:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer
```

But I can't locate the imdbpy2sql.py script, there is nothing in the bin folder:

```
/bin$ ls | grep imdb
/bin$
```

How do I find the script?

I've tried to install package from PyPI, it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the package has been installed from third party repository (site-package) it is stored in:`~/. local/bin/`, as well as the imdbpy2sql.py script.